# Schema.org - Structured data pulls in the wrong numbers

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

https://www.shycart.com/scat-menstrual-cup-223-66

The markup shows 472 reviews. But, in SERP, only 1 review count is shown. Can someone advice?

[SERP results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtHi3.png)

Comment: The page contains several `Product` items, each with its own `reviewCount`. Are you aware of this? If yes, do you do something to convey which `Product` the page is about?

Comment: Thanks @unor for the reply. I have defined it is as **collectionpage**. In the guidelines, it is mentioned that a collectionpage can contain many products. The structured data testing tool also reflects the number correctly. But, the rendering in the SERP shows the data as that of the last product.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **unor**. Your many separate types **Product** contradict **[Google’s Guide for Product](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)**:

> There are two types of pages where you would typically use this
>   markup: a product page that describes a single product a shopping
>   aggregator page that lists a single product, along with information
>   about different sellers offering that product

And further:

> Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.